# Recalculate atom positions to account for periodic boundary conditions

Tags: software, periodic-boundary-conditions, vmd, minimum-image-convention

I have the output of a simulation done using Periodic boundary conditions (PBC), however, the atom positions have been resolved, i.e. there are atoms outside the PBC-box now. Is there a software/formula that I can use to restore these positions back inside the box?

I have an `.xyz` file that contains the positions of the atoms.

Comment: I assume you want to use vmd: https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/pbctools/ There is the option to   pbc set {a b c alpha betta gamma} -all   and then you can use pbc wrap

Comment: Depends on what you actually have, if you have a trajectory in xtc or similar formats, you could try centering the trajectory to the center of geometry/mass, even using gromacs tools for that, `trjconv` explicitely with the `-fit rot+trans` argument. That said, I feel more details are needed to answer the question for real.

Comment: @IvanP I have added the file format as part of the question

Comment: @Fabian your solution looks good. is there a way to specify a different pbc box for each config and get the position of these "wrapped" atoms in a file using vmd itself ?

Comment: @fireball.1 You can specify a different box for each frame using the -frame option to pbc set. VMD cannot write the coordinates back to an xyz file, but other formats are supported. I would only recommend VMD for visualization of the trajectory though. What is your goal? I only mentioned VMD because you tagged it, so I assumed you wanted to visualize and not process the coordinates.

Comment: @Fabian i wish to visualize and process on the data

Comment: You can use “wrap” command of ATOMSK. Check this link https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/doc.php

Comment: @Sufyan Why not write an answer? Please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/74/5

Comment: @NikeDattani I finally got time to write the answer :) Though my answer does not have much explanation to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To visualize the trajectory you can use VMD and use its pbctools

```
vmd trajectory.xyz
> pbc set {a b c alpha betta gamma} -all
> pbc wrap
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are the lattice vectors and `alpha`, `beta`, and `gamma` the angles. The angles can be omitted if the box is orthorhombic. For more information see here: https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/pbctools

To process the trajectory I'd recommend using one of the available python packages. Here is a code snippet using the Atomic Simulation Environment (ASE):

```
from ase import io
xyz=io.read('trajectory.xyz',index=":")
for frame in xyz:
  frame.set_cell([a,b,c],[alpha,beta,gamma])
  frame.set_pbc([True,True,True])
  frame.wrap()
io.xyz.write_xyz('trajectory_wrapped.xyz',xyz)
```

Because the xyz-file contains no information about the cell you have to supply it separately. You can also use ASE to further process the coordinates if you wish. The documentation is here: https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/

Comment: Very helpful indeed! +1. Please take a look at my edit, in case you didn't know that text can be stylized as `code` in-line as well as in the "code blocks" that you wrote.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ATOMSK](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr).

The command:
`atomsk initial.xyz -wrap final.xyz`
will wrap all the atom coordinates back into your simulation box.
`initial.xyz` is your input file and `final.xyz` is the output after wrapping all atoms back into the simulation box.

You can get the output in many different formats. ATOMSK is quite powerful and simple to use. Please have a look at its [documentation](https://atomsk.univ-lille.fr/doc.php).

Comment: +1. Welcome back after so long away! It's an excellent answer, and perfect for this site. You're too hard on yourself in this comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/recalculate-atom-positions-to-account-for-periodic-boundary-conditions?noredirect=1#comment6890_3961